# How to evaluate call a function defined in a code block?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I expected 'lorem ipsum' for the code below. What am I doing wrong?

```
#+NAME: foo
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
  (defun foo () (insert "lorem ipsum"))
#+END_SRC

;; C-c C-c
#+CALL: foo()

#+RESULTS:
: foo
```

UPDATE

Based on the answer I did this:

```
#+NAME: foo
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp
  (defun foo () "lorem ipsum")
#+END_SRC

#+name: bar 
#+begin_src elisp
(foo)
#+end_src

;; C-c C-c
#+CALL: bar()
```

And I'm getting this message: "Symbol's function definition is void".

Comment: Just try the right thing you want to achieve: `(foo)`

Comment: @Claudio I see what you mean: `(foo) C-x C-e`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#+NAME: foo
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results silent
  (defun foo () (insert "lorem ipsum"))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: foo

#+name: bar
#+begin_src elisp
(foo)
#+end_src

;; C-c C-c
#+CALL: bar()
```

IOW, the `foo` code block when executed just defines the function, it does not call it. The `bar` code block however calls the function that was defined by the first code block. Typing `C-c C-c` on the `#+CALL: bar()` line runs the `bar` code block, which runs the function, which inserts the text (and depending on *where* you type `C-c C-c`, you'll get the text inserted in somewhat unexpected places).

EDIT: The function `foo` *inserts* the text in the buffer and returns `nil` (that's what the last form in its body i.e. `(insert "...")` returns). So you get the text inserted in the buffer (and depending on *where* you type `C-c C-c`, you'll get it inserted in various places on the `#+CALL: bar` line). Meanwhile the `#+RESULTS` will contain what the function returned, i.e. `nil` (it is suppressed in the "normal" output of a code block but you can see it if e.g. you specify `:results drawer`).

If you want the function to *return* the text (rather than insert it in the buffer), then write the function like this:

```
(defun foo () "lorem ipsum")
```

This *returns* the string as its value and that is then put in the `#+RESULTS` block (as long as `:results value` is in effect, which it is by default in `elisp` code blocks). Plus you don't get the text inserted in more or less arbitrary places in the buffer.

EDIT 2: In answer to some additional questions/comments by the OP, the `foo` code block has to be evaluated first: it defines the function `foo` that is used by the `bar` code block. You always have to define something before you can use it.

Adding a `:results silent` header argument to the `foo` code block makes sure that any results output is suppressed. The code block is still evaluated: any output is thrown away. Make sure that you spell it correctly: the header argument is `:results` with no space between the colon and the word. See [Using header aruments](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-Header-Arguments.html) in the Org mode manual.

Comment: I'm getting `lorem ipsum` followed by `#+RESULTS:`. Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: The function *inserts* the text in the buffer at whatever place you were when you pressed `C-c C-c`, but the function returns `nil` (which is what the `insert` call returns). If you want the function to *return* the string (rather than insert it in the buffer), then see my edit.

Comment: I updated my post based on your edit.

Comment: You need to *define* the function `foo` by pressing `C-c C-c` on the `foo` code block. Only after it is defined, can it be called.

Comment: Pressing `C-c C-c` on the foo code block inserts `#+RESULTS: foo
: foo`. I was hoping `elisp : results silent` would prevents that, but it does not. Any suggestion, please?

Comment: Yes, use `:results silent` with no space between the colon and `results`.

Comment: How would I make the code block for `bar` silent without impeding the call to it (it does if I do `:results silent`)?

Comment: Please no questions  in the comments. I've made a couple of exceptions already, but this is the last one: `:results silent` suppresses the output; it does not inhibit the evaluation.  If you have an additional question, ask a new question.